# Hales' generalization of the stacked bases theorem (seeking a proof)

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, abelian-groups, elementary-proofs

In his paper [Analogues of the stacked bases theorem](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0068211), published in the proceedings of a 1976 conference, A.W. Hales claimed some interesting generalizations of the stacked bases theorem for abelian groups, but he didn't include the proofs because he saw them "messy" and was hoping to find some kind of canonical form yielding his generalizations in a more elegant way. In private communication, Hales has commented that in the end he didn't pursue the matter further, and that no write-up of the original proofs exists. I have searched the literature, but I haven't been able to find any proof of his statements: two papers refer to his ([Representations over PID's with three distinguished submodules](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2000-352-05/S0002-9947-00-02281-9/home.html), [Half-factorial subsets in infinite abelian groups](https://imsc.uni-graz.at/geroldinger/45-half-factorial-subsets.pdf)), but only tangentially, or so seems to me (the first one does not even cite Hale's paper in the text, just adds the reference!). Below I condense the ideas and results of the paper:

Let $A$ be an abelian group and $0\rightarrow \ker f\rightarrow F\rightarrow^f A\rightarrow 0$ be a presentation with $F$ free. We write $(F,f)$ for the presentation and $(F,f,X,R)$ for the presentation with fixed basis $X$ of $F$ and fixed system of generators $R\subseteq F$ for $\ker f$ (we say we have *completed* $(F,f)$ with $X,R$). Given the presentation $(F,f,X,R)$, define the *length* $l(R)$ as the supremum of $l(r)$ over all $r\in R$, where $l(r)$ is the number of nonzero coefficients of $r$ written in basis $X$. Observe that for any abelian group a presentation can be found such that $l(R)\leq 3$, by taking $F$ with basis $A$ and all relations of the form $x+y-z$ where $z=x+y$. Clearly, an abelian group has $l(R)=0$ for some presentation iff it is free, and has some presentation with $l(R)\leq1$ iff it is a direct sum of cyclic groups, since it is of the form $F/H$ with $F$ generated by $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $H$ generated by $\{a_ix_i\}_{i\in I}$ with $a_I\in A$. A group with some presentation with $l(R)\leq2$ is called *simply presented*. With this terminology in mind we can restate the stacked bases theorem as follows: Let $A$ have a presentation of the form $(F_0,f_0,X_0,R_0)$ with $l(R_0)\leq1$. Then any presentation $(F,f)$ can be completed with $X,R$ so that $l(R)\leq1$. This version allows for generalization, parametrized by $l(R)$, which we will call assertion SBT$(n)$: If an abelian group $A$ has a presentation $(F_0,f_0,X_0,R_0)$ with $l(R_0)\leq n$ then all presentations $(F,f)$ can be completed with $X,R$ such that $l(R)\leq n$ (so the stacked bases theorem is SBT$(1)$, which is true). By the observations above, the only interesting cases left to study are SBT$(0)$, SBT$(2)$ and SBT$(3)$. The result SBT$(0)$ is false as it stands, since $f_0$ is an isomorphism from $F_0$ to $A$, but this needs not be the case for any free module $F$. We can sightly modify it to a true assertion SBT'$(0)$: If $A$ has a presentation with $l(R_0)=0$ then all presentations $(F,f)$ can be completed with $X,R$ such that $R\subseteq X\cup\{0\}$. This is true because $A$, having $l(R_0)=0$, is free, so any short exact sequence presenting $A$ splits, hence $F\cong A\oplus\ker f$ and we get the desired basis for $F$. Assertions SBT$(2)$ and SBT$(3)$ are claimed by Hales to be true, i.e., if $A$ is simply presented then any presentation can be made simply presented, and any presentation of an abelian group can be completed with a basis $X$ and set of relations $R$ such that $l(R)\leq3$ in basis $X$.

My specific questions are:

1. Can we give a proof of SBT(2) and SBT(3), or some counterexample?
2. Can the results be extended to modules over other rings, e.g. PIDs?